# Линейные списки, оформление задачи

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Перед открытием двух железнодорожных касс сформировались
2 очереди пассажиров,  причем некоторые из них находятся сразу
в  обеих очередях.  Для каждого пассажира известны его места в
очередях и необходимое время обслуживания.  Если у какого-либо
пассажира очереди подходят одновременно, то он обслуживается в
первой   кассе.   Промоделировать   работу    касс,    выдавая
последовательно информацию об обслуживании пассажиров.

Над данной лабораторной я думаю уже неделю. Немного не понимаю, как правильно оформить МИНУТЫ.
Допустим я имею файл и в нём

```
1 касса: А(1)[2]
2 касса: B(1)[3]
```

К примеру буква это имя пасажира, int в () это его место в очереди, [] это минуты? Или как ещё можно оформить минуты, которые даны каждому пасс. на его обслуживание?

Comment: Уж про неделю-то не надо привирать. Не имеет совершенно никакого значения, как оформлять.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делаете набор (вектор, список, массив...)  структур наподобие таких

```
struct  passenger {
    string Name; 
    int places[2]; 
    int time
}
```

и на каждом шаге выбираете пассажиров из числа необслуженных с минимальным местом в очереди свободной кассы, выводите, затем удаляете из набора. Время следующего шага определяется как текущее плюс время обработки данного пассажира